# How to pass double[] from c# to c++ using SWIG

Tags: c#, swig

I have a c++ class and a member function uses two double array as input like:

```
class model{
//define some varible..
void Trainmodel(double *x,double *y);
//...
};
```

I wanted to use this class in c# and followed the example in `./swigwin2.0.9/examples/csharp/arrays` and the guide in help page: [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#CSharp_arrays)
my model.MY file is like:

```
%module model_dll 
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "model.h"
%}
/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "model.h"
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%apply double INPUT[]  { double* x }
%apply double INPUT[] { double* y }
```

but when I use this function in c#, an error occurs:
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for `model.Trainmodel(SWIGTYPE_p_double, SWIGTYPE_p_double)` has some invalid arguments
and
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from `double[]` to `SWIGTYPE_p_double`

I check the source code of model.cs and found the trainmodel function like this:

```
public int Trainmodel(SWIGTYPE_p_double x, SWIGTYPE_p_double y) {
//do something
}
```

could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with these codes? Why swig generate  `SWIGTYPE_p_double` instead of `double []`?

---

I copy the example code in SWIG below:

c# code:

```
int[] source = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] target = new int[ source.Length ];

example.myArrayCopy( source, target, target.Length );
```

c code:

```
void myArrayCopy( int* sourceArray, int* targetArray, int nitems ) {
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < nitems; i++ ) {
targetArray[ i ] = sourceArray[ i ];
}
}
```

.i warp file:

```
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%apply int INPUT[]  {int *sourceArray}
%apply int OUTPUT[] {int *targetArray}
```

am I missing something?

---

SORRY 
I made such a stupid mistake.(WTF! :-( ) in the *.i file, the code " %include "model.h" " should put after these code "%include "arrays_csharp.i" %apply ..." not before. So the right form is:

```
%module model_dll 
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "model.h"
%}
/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%apply double INPUT[]  { double* x }
%apply double INPUT[] { double* y }
%include "model.h"//BE CAREFUL: this should put after the include"arrays_csharp.i"
```

the problem is solved. and anyone who want include arrays_csharp.i, please make sure the "include" code and the "apply" code is written before include your own .h file (model.h in this case).

Comment: I cant see any double array in yoir c++ code or am I wrong? You can also import your C++ dll without swig over DllImport in c#

Comment: *x *y are pointers point to two double array

Comment: Im not developing in C++, but I tought so and I got a kind of confirmation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719051/array-of-pointers-as-function-parameter that the x and y pointers arent arrays, but it can still be that im wrong, but I would suggest to try to change `(double *x, double *y)` to `(*double x[], *double y[])`