# using an array of pointers as a parameter of a function

Tags: c++

so was trying to make an array of pointers to objects and pass it to a function but am getting errors.
i have declared an array.

```
shapes *myArray[2];
```

having a function

```
void addShape(shapes *myArray[]);
```

passing the array

```
addShape(myArray);
```

isnt working. error: argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int **".

what to do here?

Comment: You are the one millionth person on Stackoverflow wondering why arrays cannot be passed by value to a function. If I take **your exact question title** and paste it into the Google search text field, then the very first hit leads me to a Stackoverflow question which answers everything you are asking.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9205d0ec675c1b3). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array of pointers as function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719051/array-of-pointers-as-function-parameter)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
void addShape(shapes* (&myArray)[2]);
```

More intuitive with `std::array<shapes*, 2>` of `std::vector<shape*>`

Comment: It might make more sense to OP if you explain what `shapes *myArray[]` means as a function parameter :-)

Comment: this was an assignment where i was supposed to create an array of pointers . and a function to add shapes onto that array

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer, but I may have misunderstood the question in the first place as I cannot reproduce the problem.