# How to use pointers into structure

Tags: c++, oop, nested

I have a structure sportist

```
struct sportist{           
    string name;
    string surname;
    int goals;
    string tim;

}
```

Here is the function that should read the values.

```
 void read(sportist x[],int n)     
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        cout<<"************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Name:";
        cin>>x[i].name;
        cout<<endl<<"Surname:"; 
        cin>>x[i].surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Goals :";
        cin>>x[i].goals;
        cout<<endl<<"Name of the team:";
        cin>>x[i].tim;

    }
```

My question is how can I use pointers, because I need to? My attempt:

```
 void read(sportist* x,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        cout<<"************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Name:";
        cin>>x->name;
        cout<<endl<<"Surname:"; 
        cin>>x->surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Goals :";
        cin>>x->goals;
        cout<<endl<<"Name of the team:";
        cin>>x->tim;

    }
}
```

What I want is to sort the sequence of athletes and teams by the number of goals and print them on the screen to sort them in a popup order. But it shows me errors when I debug.

Comment: C++ does provide lists, vectors and smart pointers (and so on). If you don't have to use c-style arrays and raw pointers, don't do it

Comment: My assignment is to use pointers too. That's why @RoQuOTriX

Comment: You're already using pointers. In a parameter type, `sportist x[]` is equivalent to `sportist* x`.  `sportist* x[]` is the same as `sportist** x`.

Comment: Maybe you should add this to the question, that you NEED to use pointers ;)

Comment: Define "use pointers." Do you need to pass a pointer, or an array of pointers?

Comment: An array of pointers @Chipster

Comment: Hmm, [looks like you got it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1719073/10957435). Are you getting an error? If so, can you add it to your question?

Comment: Nipicking but it's not possible to pass an array to a function in C++. Everything is done with pointers not arrays.

Comment: I edited my question(my attempt). I assume I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

you should pay attention to one point when you are using array `x[i]` with `i` increasing ,you are traversing the array ,but with pointer you should move pointer so it would point to next elements of array.You should use `x++;`.

look:

```
void read(sportist* x, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        cout << "************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "Name:";
        cin >> x->name;
        cout << endl << "Surname:";
        cin >> x->surname;
        cout << endl << "Goals :";
        cin >> x->goals;
        cout << endl << "Name of the team:";
        cin >> x->tim;
        x++;
    }
}
```

if you miss `x++;` each time you will write entered data in first element of array.

Also note in function you are declaring this array of `sportist` , if you declare `sportist* x` instead of `sportist x[num]` ,you have to allocate memory for it too.

Comment: How can I allocate memory?

Comment: @Klea you should use `malloc` like this `sportist * x=(sportist *)malloc(sizeof(sportist));`

Comment: Where  should I ? @hanie

Comment: because when you define an array required  memory will be reserved ,but with pointers it's not like that.Check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)