# Pass array of struct pointers to function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Trying to pass array of struct pointers to function `doIt()` . Looks my way is not correct since I can't get right second array element:

```
struct c {
    int a;
    char* b;
};


struct cc {
    int a;
    c* b;
};

char a[] = "aaa";
char b[] = "bbb";
char e[] = "eee";

c d1 = {1,a};
c d2 = {2,b};
c d3 = { 12,e };

cc g1 = { 123, &d1 };
cc g2 = { 321, &d2 };
cc g3 = { 333, &d3 };



void doIt( c *  s)
{
    cout << s->b;
    s++;
    cout << s->b;
}
```

What is right way to pass array of struct pointers?

Comment: please show examples of code that calls the doIT function. Also, it would be less confusing if you didn't reuse the same names (a, b) for multiple objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719051/array-of-pointers-as-function-parameter

Comment: As shown, `doIt` doesn't take an array of pointers. It takes a pointer to an array of objects of type `c`. The rest of the code doesn't declare an array of `c` suitable for passing to this function. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Raw arrays in C (and C++) are just pointers. They point to the first element of an array. For example, if you want an array of `int`, you would write it like `int* array`. If you want an array of `struct c`, you would write it like `c* array`. If you want an array of pointers to `struct c`, you would write it like `c** array`.

To access elements, don't use `array++`, use `array[i]` where `i` is the index (position) of the element you want to access, 0 being the index of the first element, 1 the second, etc.

So, your code should look like this:

```
void doIt(c** s)
{
    cout << s[0]->b; // s[0] is the first element
    cout << s[1]->b; // s[1] is the second
}
```

Note that in C++, it is preferred to use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

```
void doIt(std::vector<c*> s)
{
    cout << s[0]->b;
    cout << s[1]->b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass array to a function you need also pass length of this array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct c {
    int a;
    char* b = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
};

void doIt(c* all, size_t length);

int main()
{
    char a[] = "aaa";
    const size_t sizeOfA = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    char b[] = "bbb";
    const size_t sizeOfB = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
    char e[] = "eee";
    const size_t sizeOfE = sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]);

    c d1 {1, a, sizeOfA}; 
    c d2 {2, b, sizeOfB};
    c d3 {12, e, sizeOfE};

    c all[] = {d1, d2, d3};
    const size_t length = sizeof(all)/sizeof(all[0]);

    doIt(all, length);

return 0;
}

void doIt(c* all, size_t length)
{
    if (!all)
    {
        std::cerr << "Pointer to array is null" << std::endl;
    }       
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < all[i].size; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << all[i].b[j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can use `std::vector`. So, you don't need to use adittional argument (length of the vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct c {
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

void doIt(const std::vector<c>& myVector);

int main()
{
    std::vector<c> myVector;
    myVector.emplace_back(1, "aaa");
    myVector.emplace_back(2, "bbb");
    myVector.emplace_back(12, "eee");

    doIt(myVector);

return 0;
}

void doIt(const std::vector<c>& myVector)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << myVector[i].b << std::endl;
    }
}
```